# how to transform strings (like age) to single value in colums?

Tags: python, string, pandas, transform

I'm new in PANDAS and I can't find a way tu transform something like this:

```
 0 AGE
 1 82 years 03 months 11 days
 2 54 years 06 months 10 days
 3 23 years 03 months 09 days
 4 60 years 02 months 13 days
```

to this:

```
0 AGE
1 82
2 54
3 23
4 60
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more approach.
Here we are [extracting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the digits at the beginning of the string using regex.

```
df["AGE"] = df["AGE"].str.extract('(^\d+)')
```

**Output**

```
    0   AGE
0   1   82
1   2   54
2   3   23
3   4   60
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip the string (to remove leading space in string, just in case), split it, then take the first item, make it an integer:

```
df["AGE"] = df["AGE"].apply(lambda x : int(x.strip().split()[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply [Timedeltas](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

```
df['AGE']=df.AGE.astype('timedelta64[Y]')
```